# Performant sort files into subdirectories by content of metafile

Tags: bash, files, mv, xargs

-edit: more details, correct code-

I want to move files from a directory into sub directories by data out of a metadata file.

There are groups of files like `<name>.<extension>`. Each group consists of 3 files. One of the files in each group has the extension `.idx`. This is the metadata file, a text file.

In the metadata file, there is exact one line like `VALUE_01=XXXXX` and some others (15 to 60 lines, `<key>=<value>`, `<key>` is unique).

Now I want to move all files `<name>.*` from the current directory to a sub directory named `XXXXX` in this case (the value to the key `VALUE_01`).

I played around with `for` loops, etc., but even a `ls *.idx` doesn't work because there are round about **2 million files** there! So it doen't work and I need some performance.

I tried

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.idx" -exec grep -H "VALUE_01=" {} ";" | perl -pe 's/(.*?).idx:VALUE_01=(.*)$/\1.* .\/\2\//'
```

So I get a list like

> ./file1.* ./XXXXX/
> ./file2.* ./XXXXX/
> ./file3.* ./YYYYY/

I tried to pass this as arguments via `xargs` to `mv`.

```
... | xargs mv
```

to get

```
mv ./<name>.* ./XXXXX/
```

but I get error messages

> mv: cannot stat './XXXXX/': No such file or directory
> mv: cannot stat './file1.*': No such file or directory
>
> mv: cannot stat './XXXXX/': No such file or directory
>
> mv: cannot stat './file2.*': No such file or directory
> mv: warning: source directory './YYYYY/' specified more than once
> mv: cannot stat './file3.*': No such file or directory

I think, it's an incorrect use of `xargs`.

I'm not good in shell programming, so I don't get the hint how to use it, or how to avoid it.

Comment: Each `.idx` file haves exact one line `VALUE_01=xxxx` (or `VALUE_01=yyyy`) and some other lines. The `idx` file must be copied, too. - I will edit my questure...

Comment: Can you show us an example of the file? Is the `VALUE_01=XXXX` the only thing in the line? Is the `XXXX` always numbers? Always letters? Always non-whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to move all the files matching `file.*` into a subdirectory retrieved from the `VALUE_01` of the corresponding `file.idx` in the same subdirectory, then a structure like this might be what you are looking for (`echo`s left in for testing):

```
find . -name '*.idx' -execdir sh -c '
  for idx do
    tgt=$(grep -m1 -Po "VALUE_01=\K.*" "$idx")
    [ -n "$tgt" ] && echo mkdir -p "$tgt" || continue
    printf "%s\0" "${idx%.idx}".* | xargs -r0 echo mv -nt "$tgt" --
  done
' sh {} +
```

Testing briefly with

```
==> ./dir/file.idx <==
VALUE_01=XXXXX

==> ./dir/foo.idx <==
VALUE_01=YYYYY
```

gives

```
$ find . -name '*.idx' -execdir sh -c '
  for idx do
    tgt=$(grep -m1 -Po "VALUE_01=\K.*" "$idx")
    [ -n "$tgt" ] && echo mkdir -p "$tgt" || continue
    printf "%s\0" "${idx%.idx}".* | xargs -r0 echo mv -nt "$tgt" --
  done
' sh {} +
mkdir -p XXXXX
mv -nt XXXXX -- ./file.idx ./file.json
mkdir -p YYYYY
mv -nt YYYYY -- ./foo.awk ./foo.idx ./foo.py
```

The `--` to end the option list is not strictly necessary since `-execdir` prepends `./` but I like it as a visual cue. The `-m1` in the `grep` just make it quit as soon as it finds a match, which *may* make a difference if the `.idx` files have a lot of following content. If you know the target directories already exist, then you can omit the `mkdir`. Alternatively you could test for existence.

Comment: Sorry for editing your code. I added `-maxdepth 1` option to prevent the script making a new subdirectory and move the files a level higher. 1. run moves files from `.` to `./XXXX/` next run moves file from `.` to `./XXXX/` and files out of `./XXXX/` to `./XXXX/XXXX/` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The trick will be to use `for file in *idx`. You don't ever want to do `for file in $(ls *idx)` anyway, see Bash pitfalll #1, and in any case, the shell cannot handle expanding so many file names, as you already saw. However, using the builtin `for` gets around the problem, so you can try something like this:

```
for file in *.idx; do
  name="${file%%.idx}"
  num=$(grep -m 1 -oP 'VALUE_01=\K\S+' "$file")
  mkdir -p "$num"
  printf 'mv %s* %s/' "$name" "$num"
done > script.sh
```

#### Explanation

- `for file in *.idx; do ... done`: iterate over all files and directories whose name ends in `.idx`, saving each as `$file`.
- `name="${file%%.idx}`: the syntax `${var%%pattern}` will return the value of `$var` with the longest match for the pattern `pattern` removed from the right hand side of the variable. See https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html. So this will return `file` if given `file.idx`.
- `num=$(grep -m 1 -oP 'VALUE_01=\K\S+' "$file")`: get the name of the target directory from the idx file. The `-m` tells `grep` to stop searching after the first match since there is no reason to process the entire file. Next, the `-o` means "print only the matching part of the line" and the `-P` enables [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) which give us `\K` for "ignore everything matched up to this point" and `\S` and `+` for "one or more non-whitespace characters". So this will look for the string `VALUE_01=` and then print the longest non-whitespace string it finds after it. Note that this assumes your `XXXX` has no whitespace.
- `mkdir -p "$num"`: create the target directory if it doesn't already exist. You want the `-p` because that makes `mkdir` simply do nothing if the directory does already exist.
- `printf 'mv %s* %s/' "$name" "$num"`: print out the commands that need to be run (e.g. `mv foo* XXXX`).
- `... done > script.sh`: capture all the commands printed by the previous step into a file called `script.sh`.

This will enable you to check the commands and try a few manually to see that they work. If they do, you can either just run `sh script.sh` to execute them, or redo the loop but this time execute the commands instead of printing them:

```
for file in *.idx; do
  name="${file%%.idx}"
  num=$(grep -m 1 -oP 'VALUE_01=\K\S+' "$file")
  mkdir -p "$num"
  mv "$name"* "$num"
done > script.sh
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it correct, that I have to use `mv "$name"*`? Otherwise I get `mv: cannot stat ...` exception.

Comment: @AndyA. yes indeed, sorry! I had it in the `printf` example but forgot to include it int he second one.